# ImageMagick read data:image/svg instead of file

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I'm attempting to convert an SVG to PNG and so far everything works great when I'm using a file (file.svg) but currently my SVG files (simple signatures) are stored in a database.

When I retrieve the vector it looks like 'data:image/svg +xml; base64,...'.  For now, I'm exporting the file using fwrite() and then running Image Magick on that, but I'd love to be able to cut out that step.

Can this be done?

My current command is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/convert /path/to/file.svg /path/to/file.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way to do this is to use Imagick. I'll go that route in the future, but getting a new install up and running on the host this site runs on would have been tediours.

Ultimately, I chose to export the SVG as an XML file and save it with the .svg extension so that it could be loaded using the syntax shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably possible to do this in a number of ways, here's one:

```
echo 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiI+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTYiIGN5PSIxNiIgcj0iOCIgZmlsbD0ibGltZSIvPjwvc3ZnPgo=' | cut -d',' -f2 | base64 -d | convert - test.png
```

It seemed like `convert` liked to have the XML prolog in the string for some reason.